# Facebook - Promt for sharing - Set prefilling text

Tags: facebook, share

I saw that you could share messages on your Facebook timeline with such a link:

`https://www.facebook.com/connect/prompt_feed.php?message=Test`

But the form/textfield isn't prefilled with that text I gave with the parameter `message`. Is that the wrong parameter or isn't that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is no longer possible.  They removed this ability this summer so that people share unique content.  If you really want to do this, you can prompt for publish_stream permissions and publish whatever you would like.